# PDF figure will not scale

Tags: graphics

I am trying to import a graphic from Excel to LaTeX. The graph has been printed on a PDF but when trying to import it into LaTeX it doesn't scale.

Using the `\fbox` function shows a box where I would like the graph to be but the graph itself is over it, justified on the left and going out of the margin on the right.

The `.pdf` file has white space around it but the use of the `trim` argument doesn't change the output.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,center]{domaine.pdf}
\caption{domaine}
\label{fig:domaine}
\end{figure}
```

Problem solved, output has to be to PDF directly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Is there any  whitespace around the graph in the PDF?

Comment: Use `\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,center]{domaine.pdf}}` to see the real space used by the image.

Comment: there is no `center` key to `\includegraphics`. You do not give many clues but I would guess that excel printed a full page image (even if it is white around the edge) scaling a full page image to the textwidth will not do much. You need to either crop the image first or use the clip or trim keys. As a debugging aid use `\fbox{\includegraphics...}` to see how big latex thinks the image is

Comment: The box is centered to text width but the graph itself is left justified and far out on the right. The pdf has indeed more white space around than the excel graph but it still doesn't scale at all.

Comment: @user72767, if your pdf image has a lot of blank space that will always be used even if you scale it. You need to trim the pdf file.

Comment: \includegraphics[trim = 30mm 30mm 30mm 30mm, clip, width=\textwidth,center]{domaine.pdf}
gives exactly the same result

Comment: Please clarify the question. Which driver for `graphicx` is specified? Which TeX engine is used (in which mode)? What is the output format (DVI, PostScript, PDF, ...)? Which viewers are used to test the result?

Comment: The output is DVI. I don't understand what you mean by driver for `graphicx`. The version is MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek ^^^^ ;-)

Comment: @JPPiedboeuf Little hint, you can ping people about news using the `@`-sign in front of the name. But everytime, the changes will be seen by a very limited amount of people. You can edit the question and add more details. The Q will go back on top on the main site.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. There is whitespace around the graph in the PDF.

Comment: I solved a similar (maybe the same) problem with `pdfcrop` - should come with your TeX distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Since the output format is DVI, it is very likely that the DVI viewer is not able to handle the scaling of PDF files. PDF as output format is a better choice here
(e.g. via pdflatex).

The documentation for package `graphicx` also explains drivers, see [Packages in the 'graphics'](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/graphics/grfguide.pdf) bundle.

Answer (score 0):

this might get you started. I took a somewhat random pdf from [here](http://%5Ccaption%7Bdomaine.pdf%20from%20p.%2016%20in%20%5Curl%7Bhttps://web.stanford.edu/group/scspi/slides/Inequality_SlideDeck.pdf) and downloaded p. 16. Looks like this

[image]

Then I ran the code below and got this.

[image: dkld]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[trim = 8mm 47mm 110mm 47mm, clip, width=10cm]{domaine.pdf}
\caption{domaine.pdf from p. 16 in \url{https://web.stanford.edu/group/scspi/slides/Inequality_SlideDeck.pdf}}
\label{fig:domaine}
\end{figure}
\blindtext


\end{document}
```